# Arrays: array_shift($arr) or $arr[0]?

Tags: php, arrays

Which one would you use?

Basically I only want to get the 1st element from a array, that's it.

Comment: None of the above. `$first = reset($array);` is what you want. Will work correctly no matter what you throw at it.

Comment: @Jon: I'd already covered that. :)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: So... should I delete the comment then?

Comment: @Jon: Nah, no use in that now. This question is strewn with duplicate responses now anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`array_shift` will actually remove the specified value from the array. Do not use it unless you really want to reduce the array!

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Answer (score 16):

Well, they do different things.

- [`array_shift($arr)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) takes the first element out of the array, and gives it to you.
- `$arr[0]` just gives it to you... *if* the array has numeric keys.

An alternative that works for associative arrays too is [`reset($arr)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php). This does move the array's internal pointer, but unless you're using those functions this is unlikely to affect you.

Answer (score 6):

You would use `$arr[ 0 ];` `array_shift` removes the first element from the array.

### EDIT

---

This answer is actually somewhere between incomplete and plain out wrong but, because the comments of the two `jon`'s I think that it should actually stay up so that others can see that discourse.

The right answer:

- `reset` is the method to return the first defined index of the array. Even in non-associative arrays, this may not be the `0` index.
- `array_shift` will remove and return the value which is found at `reset`

The OP made the assumption that `$arr[0]` is the first index is not accurate in that particular context.

Comment: the numeric/associative comment ive seen from all the other is pretty important

Comment: Based on the question, associative array is not an issue. If you `only want to get the 1st element from a array, that's it.` then this answer is correct, if not the most complete.

Comment: its not my question, and the `1st element of an array` and `arr[0]`/`element with index zero` are not equivalent in PHP

Comment: No they aren't, but I read the question akin to, "Given the choice between strawberry and pistachio, say your favorite ice cream." The correct answer is neither (big fan of cheesecake). But, assuming that I am working within the confines of those choices, I would pick strawberry.

Comment: -1: Agree with jon_darkstar. And I 'd really like to hear how you would justify that `$arr[0]` still does not work correctly with `array(1 => 1, 0 => 0)`.

Comment: sure, that makes sense to a point.  but would you extend that pattern to SO in general?  situations like this are pretty common, and its not doing the OP any favors to stay within that box

Comment: @Jon You're right. I'm wrong. @jon_darkstar Honestly, it might not be the best, but I guess I'll have to take my stripes for it until I stop doing that. It seems it is a bad habit that I've yet to break.

Comment: @both As to this current answer, I personally think it should stay up, if only to serve as a different sort of lesson than what was originally intended.

Answer (score 4):

`$arr[0]` only works if the array as numerical keys.

`array_shift` removes the element from the array and it modifies the array itself.

If you are not sure what the first key is , and you do not want to remove it from the array, you could use:

```
<?php
foreach($arr $k=>$v){
   $value = $v;
   break;
}
```

or even better:

```
<?php
reset($arr);
$value = current($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an associative Array you can also use `reset($arr)`: It returns the first Element (doesn't remove), and sets the array pointer to this element.

But the fastest way is `$arr[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to modify the `arr` array also?  `array_shift` removes the first element of the array and returns it, thus the array has changed.  `$arr[0]` merely gives you the first element.

I would use `$arr[0]` unless I explicitly wanted to modify the array.  You may add code later to use the `arr` array and forget that it was modified.

Answer (score 1):

given what you need, $arr[0] is preferrable, because it's faster. array_shift is used in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

arrshift is more reliable and will always return the first element in the array, but this also modifies the array by removing that element.

arr[0] will fail if your array doesn't start at the 0 index, but leaves the array itself alone.

A more convoluted but reliable method is:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$first = $arr[$keys[0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first element of an array, use $arr[0] form. Advantages - Simplicity, Readability and Maintainability. Keep things straight forward.

Edit: Use index 0 only if you know that the array has default keys starting from 0.

Comment: And also breakability for a lot of possible inputs, e.g. `array('foo' => 'bar')` or `array(1 => 1, 0 => 0)`.

Comment: If you think about it, your answer now reads as follows: *To read the first element of `$arr`, use `$arr[0]`. However, you can only do that  if the first element has the key `0`.* It might not be misleading, but it's not exactly useful. Why not make it useful? :)

Answer (score 1):

with array_shif you have two operations:

1. retrive the firs element
2. shift the array

if you access by index, actually you have only one operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the array in question, use `$arr[0]` (which merely gets the first element), otherwise if you want to remove the first element of `$arr` from `$arr`, use `array_shift($arr)`.

For example:

```
$arr=array(3,-6,2);
$foo=$arr[0]; //$foo==3 and $arr==array(3,-6,2).
$bar=array_shift($arr); //$bar==3 and $arr==array(-6,2).
```

ETA:  As others have pointed out, be sure that your array isn't an associative array (ie the keys are 0,1,...,`(sizeof($arr)-1)`), otherwise this probably won't work.